# Transport Connect Reset

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ryanpa/Documents/Softlayer Scripts/getVlans.py", line 8, in <module>
    all_vlans = client['Account'].getNetworkVlans(mask='type, id, vlanNumber,name, primaryRouter.hostname, primaryRouter.datacenter, networkSpace')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 392, in call_handler
    return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 360, in call
    return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 263, in call
    return self.transport(request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 199, in __call__
    raise exceptions.TransportError(0, str(ex))
SoftLayer.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(0): ('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

When running a simple python script. I've sent the same file to my teammate to execute with my username and API key and it works for him but not on my end. I'm running this from home and i've tried on 2 different networks along with being on VPN.

```
all_vlans = client['Account'].getNetworkVlans(mask='type, id, vlanNumber,name, primaryRouter.hostname, primaryRouter.datacenter, networkSpace')

pp(all_vlans)
```

is all i'm trying to do. just simple test to get all vlans

Answer (score 0):

If you tested in other environment with your credentials and it works fine, the issue is from your side (your environment), try this in a clean environment.

Comment: Thanks for responding. How would you clean an environment?

Comment: This seems to be an error with client libraries, have seen python and C# now

Comment: If the same call works with curl, what are the SL client libraries doing that is different?

Comment: Really sorry, there was an issue with xml endpoint, unfortunately it was reported after I answered in this forum, but not it is working fine. Let me know any doubt or comments.

Comment: Still experiencing issues (different from before), working on a minimal example

Answer (score 0):

So, now we have at least 4 people having the same issue. FYI, this post is the same, me and one other person. [SoftLayer (multiple) client responding with errors after API upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938562/softlayer-apis-responding-with-invalid-credentials-for-valid-credentials)

Answer (score 0):

thi was a softlayer issue, please try again it should be fixed

Regards